# Meaning of "Reinlichkeit" in the context of Nietzsche's "Die fröhliche Wissenschaft"

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, german-to-english

I am translating a text from Nietzsche, who uses the word *Reinlichkeit* in a discussion of Schopenhauer, asking what attracts people to him. I am wondering whether I have translated the passage correctly. It seems to me that something like 'scrupulousness' is meant here.

(I would appreciate answers in English.)

> Ist es sein harter Thatsachen-Sinn, sein guter Wille zu Helligkeit und
>   Vernunft, der ihn oft so englisch und so wenig deutsch erscheinen
>   lässt? Oder die Stärke seines intellectuellen Gewissens, das einen
>   lebenslangen Widerspruch zwischen Sein und Wollen aushielt und ihn
>   dazu zwang, sich auch in seinen Schriften beständig und fast in jedem
>   Puncte zu widersprechen?
>
> Is it his exacting matter-of-fact approach, his insistence upon
>   clarity and common sense, which often makes him appear so English, and
>   so unlike Germans? Or is it the strength of his intellectual
>   conscience, which endured a life-long conflict between ‘being’ and
>   ‘willing’, and made him contradict himself constantly even in his
>   writings, and on almost every point?
>
> Oder seine Reinlichkeit in Dingen der Kirche und des christlichen
>   Gottes?—denn hierin war er reinlich wie kein deutscher Philosoph
>   bisher, so dass er "als Voltairianer" lebte und starb. Oder seine
>   unsterblichen Lehren von der Intellectualität der Anschauung, von der
>   Apriorität des Causalitätsgesetzes, von der Werkzeug-Natur des
>   Intellects und der Unfreiheit des Willens?
>
> Or is it his strict orthodoxy [conservatism] with regard to Church
>   affairs and the Christian God?  —  for here he was as orthodox
>   [conservative] as no German philosopher had ever been before, so that
>   he lived and died ‘as a Voltairian’. Or is it his immortal doctrines
>   of the intellectuality of perception, the a priori nature of the law
>   of causality, the instrumental character of the intellect, and the
>   restriction of the will?

Comment: [Reinheit](http://www.dict.cc/?s=reinheit), [Reinlichkeit](http://www.dict.cc/?s=reinlichkeit).

Comment: It does not take a native speaker to tell two words with completely different meaning apart.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... however, I do feel like our contemporary "Reinlichkeit" is not what Nietzsche had in mind. Does the passage mean that he's thorough at brooming the church? I don't think so. "Reinheit" would make more sense here, just going by the words. That said, I don't know if it's possible to answer that question without profound knowledge of the character of the person described or some insight as to how Nietzsche perceived the word "Reinlichkeit"

Comment: Carston: Bilingual dictionaries give similar equivalents for both terms.

Comment: Fastidiousness?

Comment: Not the question you were asking, but I wonder if I'm misreading the last phrase in the passage if I see it as "the utilitarian nature of the intellect and the absence of free will"?

Comment: 'absence of free will' and 'restriction of the will' are essentially equivalent. Yours may be a bit better. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Ich bin nicht im Ansatz ein Experte für Nietzsche, und ich halte es für möglich, das selbiger hier seinen eigenen Gebrauch des Wortes pflegte und man diese Passage nur im Kontext seines Werkes und des von ihm hier beschriebenen Schopenhauer verstehen kann.

Mir scheint aber, dass ein Blick in Grimms Wörterbuch durchaus hilfreich sein könnte. [Der entsprechende Band ist 1890 erschienen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GR03812&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&mainmode=DWBLieferungen), also ungefähr zur Zeit Nietzsches entstanden. (Das hier im Blickpunkt stehende Werk "Fröhliche Wissenschaft" erschienen 1882.) Im Eintrag zum Adjektiv / Adverb [reinlich](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GR03821#XGR03821) lesen wir:

> **2)** *freierer, übertragener gebrauch; deutlich, rein, correct, vom musikalischen vortrag:* ein reinliches spiel, reinliche technik; *ebenso auf das logische bezogen:* der recensent legte den gang meines vortrages kürzlich und reinlich dar. Göthe 58, 130; eine reinliche rechnung, ableitung *u. ähnl.; offen, der wahrheit gemäsz:* ich habe mein lebelang die beziehungen zum andern menschen reinlich behandelt. halbheit in neigung und abneigung ist mir unerträglich. Freytag *verl. handschr. 3, 264; von innerer klarheit und ordnung:* mit der sicherheit, welche gründliche sprachstudien zu verleihen pflegen, mit den reinlichen trieben einer angeborenen inneren oekonomie des geistes faszte er das ihm dargebotene theologische element.

*Reinlichkeit* wird ähnlich und insbesondere unter Verweis auf das Adjektiv erklärt. Zeitgenössische Leser könnten also verstanden haben

1. eine deutliche, reine und korrekte Argumentation Schopenhauers hinsichtlich Kirche und Gott
2. ein offener, der Wahrheit verpflichteter Umgang Schopenhauers mit diesem Thema
3. das Vorliegen einer inneren Klarheit und Ordnung zu diesen Begriffen bei Schopenhauer

1.) entspricht nach meinem Verständnis grob der übertragenen Bedeutung von [reinlich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/reinlich#Bedeutung2), die der Duden auch heute noch beschreibt. Für mich wäre aber 3.) am plausibelsten, wobei die beiden anderen mit hineinspielen könnten. Aber wie gesagt: dazu sollte sich jemand äußern, der mit den beiden Personen besser vertraut ist.

Die Frage, was die passende englische Übersetzung ist, wäre dann eigentlich eher was für unsere englische Schwester-Seite. *Scrupulousness* würde evtl. zu 1.) passen. Für 3.) könnte ich mir *lucidity* gut vorstellen.

Der Vollständigkeit halber und da auch nach dem Unterschied zwischen *Reinheit* und *Reinlichkeit* gefragt wurde: zu diesem Punkt kann ich mich nur der Antwort von guidot anschließen.

Comment: An answer in English would be far more helpful.

Comment: @Ornello I'd regret it if you had problems reading my answer, which I didn't expect. But still, I disagree. If you believe in your own words, namely the question title, all readers of your question, and hence my answer, will be German natives. Additionally, one third of my answer is a quote from a German dictionary and another third is directly referecing that quote. It would make no sense to translate the former, and it would mess up the latter. And whoever is capable to cope with these two, not to mention your question, should have no problems with the remaining (and least important) third.

Comment: It takes much longer to read your German than Nietzsche's.

Comment: @Ornello... I find that extremely hard to believe.

Comment: I am quite familiar with Nietzsche's vocabulary. He uses many of the same words over and over again. Also, look here: https://books.google.com/books?id=clFFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA15&dq=Reinlichkeit&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5D3aVL-lFMGuyASqzoDQDw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Reinlichkeit&f=false

Answer (score 5):

Shortly summarized: *Reinheit* (purity being the best equivalent) is a state of having no soiling or not being stained, while *Reinlichkeit* is the intention or habit of reaching that state.

Comment: Fastidiousness?

Comment: @Ornello: in case *fastidiousness* could also be used in this more metaphorical context in English this indeed appears to be a good match.

Comment: How does that apply to this context?

Answer (score 3):

You have to know your Schopenhauer in order to answer your question. It is not possible to answer your question simply by word translation. Also, you have to consider that this is 19th century writing. 'Reinheit des Denkens' = 'purity of thinking' is a common term used in German. 'Reinlichkeit des Denkens' is not a term you would use today. On the other hand there is the term 'gründliche Reinigung' which translates to 'thorough cleaning' which somebody would do who favors 'Reinlichkeit'. My guess is that the meaning of the section is somewhere in between and that there is some wordplay involved.

Comment: The phrase is 'seine Reinlichkeit in Dingen der Kirche und des christlichen Gottes', not 'Reinlichkeit des Denkens'. This is why I am leaning toward the translation I have here: 'strict orthodoxy [conservatism] with regard to Church affairs and the Christian God'. Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: @Ornello Schopenhauer was an atheist. I would be surprised if orthodoxy would be a good fit for describing his convictions.

Comment: That's why I am puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

Today, *Reinlichkeit* mainly translates as *cleanliness,* whereas *Reinheit* translates as *cleanness* or *purity.*

However, the vague descriptions in some dictionaries suggest that the use of *Reinlichkeit* was more liberal in former times.

*Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen* by dtv gives three German meanings for *Reinlichkeit:*

- *Sauberkeit* (perhaps cleanliness, cleanness)
- *Genauigkeit* (perhaps meticulousness, accurateness, precision, exactness)
- *Sorgfalt* (perhaps neatness, carefulness)

Comment: I found something: https://books.google.com/books?id=clFFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA15&dq=Reinlichkeit&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5D3aVL-lFMGuyASqzoDQDw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Reinlichkeit&f=false

Comment: maybe orderlyness?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think for one moment the Nietzsche means “orthodoxy” or “conservatism”. Quite the contrary. He says of Schopenhauer “dass er als ‘Voltairianer’ lebte und starb”, Voltairianer meaning “non-Christian, atheist”. From Nietzsche's position that is praise. He is saying that S. was not polluted or contaminated “in Dingen der Kirche und des christlichen Gottes”. You might try “detachment”, but that is perhaps a bit too weak.